# Wizard to manage page presentation

Tags: workflow

Imagine you want to buy a house.  Lots of questions about education, work history, personal information, where have you lived in the past, on and on.  These things organize into various SFDC objects and custom objects.  I was thinking it would be cool to present the user pages from these different objects to allow them to review or edit.

Like a wizard that pulls up the contact form for the person and then guides them through the related objects on work history, education, etc. rather than say a Flow that uses screens.

Writing VF and/or Apex is gonna take way too long.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Flow, aka Lightning Flow is the out of the box approach. Take a look at [Flow Builder](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/flow-builder) trailhead

Comment: This approach involves building screens to prompt the user right?  Right now my 20 page PDF manual form has over 800 fields.  I'm thinking to build that in a FLOW screen(s) is gonna take a long time.  Seems like finding some way to pop-up existing object pages would be faster I just don't know how to pull that off.

Comment: Sounds like you need to create a custom component that ingests your PDF and spits out "code" (or metadata) for your screens - Lightning Web Component, Flow, etc.